# Can't fix "missing 1 required positional argument error"

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok so, I am trying to make a shop like thing where you can take whatever you type into a box and also return the thing you typed. The bag/backpack would have 3 slots. The code I came up with is

```
    from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("BagAttempt")
canvas = Canvas(width = 1440, height = 810, bg = 'white')
canvas.pack()

shoplist=["sword","rock","flint","shield","alcohol","stick","bottle"]
backpacklist=[]
def backpackadd(Shopchoice):
    help1=0
    while shoplist[help1]!=Shopchoice:
        help1=help1+1
    if shoplist[help1]==Shopchoice:
        backpacklist.append(shoplist[help1])
        shoplist.remove(shoplist[help1])
    return shoplist,backpacklist
def Shopchoices1():
    canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,1440,810,fill="black")
    canvas.create_text(720,415,text=shoplist,font="Times 25",fill="white")
    canvas.create_text(720,705,text=backpacklist,font="Times 20",fill="white")
    leave=0
    canvas.create_text(720,565,text="What would you like to add/remove/leave:",fill="white",font="Times 10")
    Shopchoice=Entry(canvas,bg="grey",fg="white",font="Times 25")
    Shopchoice_window =canvas.create_window(720,605, anchor="n", window=Shopchoice)
    Add= Button(canvas, text = "Add", command = backpackadd, anchor = "n")
    Add.configure(width = 100, bg="yellow",activebackground = "#FFD700", relief = FLAT)
    Add_window = canvas.create_window(720,475, anchor="n", window=Add)
Shopchoices1()

mainloop()
```

I keep running into the `backpackadd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Shopchoice'` error. I am not sure how to fix it and would be thankful for help.

Comment: Please always add the full traceback for Python exceptions, and tell us what the code *should do instead*. What input do we have to give this code to reproduce the error?

Comment: You gave the `Add` button the function `backpackadd` as the callback, but that callback takes an argument. Buttons can't guess what argument that should be. What did you expect `Shopchoice` to be here?

Comment: I'd rename the argument to something that differs from the entry box, then use `lambda: backpackadd(Shopchoice.get())` as the command; that'll call an anonymous function (`lambda: ...`) which then in turn calls `Shopchoice.get()` and passes the result of that to `backpackadd()`.

Comment: When I tried that, it said there was a syntax error with the colon

Comment: the full error is ```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nbmcg\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: backpackadd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Shopchoice'```

Comment: `Add = Button(canvas, text="Add", command=lambda: backpackadd(Shopchoice.get()), anchor="n")` works just fine, no syntax errors.